# Translate and distinguish “reliability” and “dependability” in the context of software systems

Tags: english-to-german, difference, single-word-request, technical-terminology

I'm having a hard time translating the word *dependability* in the context of software systems. Intuitively I would translate it as *Zuverlässigkeit*, synonymously to *reliability.*

But reading [this paper](http://drum.lib.umd.edu/bitstream/handle/1903/6459/TR_2004-47.pdf?sequence=1) got me thinking. It states that *dependability* encompasses *reliability:*

> As  developed  over  the  past  three  decades,  dependability is  an 
>   integrating  concept  that  encompasses the following attributes:
>
> - **availability**: readiness for correct service;
> - **reliability**: continuity of correct service;
> - **safety**: absence of catastrophic consequences on the user(s) and the environment;
> - **integrity**: absence of improper system alterations;
> - **maintainability**: ability to undergo modifications, and repairs.

So my question is how to translate *dependability* and *reliability* in this context in a way that captures this distinction?

This is also discussed on Leo [here](http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=520672) and [here](http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idThread=873954), yet there is no real answer.

Comment: As a software systems researcher, I often use the word "Ausfallsicherheit" to express pretty much what you listed above regarding "dependability".

Comment: Verlässlichkeit?

Comment: @JohannesBüttner: I disagree. Counterproof: dependability encompasses maintainability but imho Ausfallsicherheit does not encompass Wartbarkeit.

Comment: Of course, you can pick any two terms such as "Zuverlässigkeit", "Verläßlichkeit", "Betriebssicherheit", "Ausfallsicherheit", and use one of them to translate "dependability" and the other one to translate "reliability". You'll have to define them, but the English terms are not self-explanatory either. It gets tricky if you also want that software engineers used to the English terms know immediately which of the newly coined German terms corresponds to which of the established English terms. ...

Comment: ... In the end, the solution might be analogous to the well-known
"safety vs. security" problem: In a context where
the distinction between "safety" and "security" is irrelevant,
both are translated by "Sicherheit". If the distinction is
important, the English terms are used instead.

Comment: @problemofficer: I'm aware of that, but imo - just as Uwe said - the meaning of these terms is often just a matter of definition. I just wanted to answer this question from a technical point of view.

Comment: Ich bin nicht sicher, ob man damit was anfangen kann, aber in der Statistik betrachtet man als Maße für die Zuverlässigkeit Reliabilität und Validität. Ersteres bedeutet, dass das Verfahren reproduzierbar ist, das zweite, dass es das misst, was gemessen werden soll. Womöglich kann man reliability einfach mit Reliabilität übersetzen und die Verantwortung so auf den Leser schieben. :) Womöglich ist der etablierte Jargon in der Softwareentwicklung aber anders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a generic engineering point of view, ***Betriebssicherheit*** might be best fitting for ***dependability***.
This term is usually applied to a technical (mechanical) structure in German but could also be applied to software when viewed as a systemic whole.

However there is no good generic term in German language. The definition you gave and also [Wikipedia’s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependability) define *dependability* as a mixture of several attributes that are already very broad on their own. In reality, software in general is seldom measured like this (it probably should). I am afraid this is why there is no term yet. Thus, for a final translation, the  context is important.

By contrast, ***reliability*** is a term which measures a software from an end-user point of view which usually does not include service, support or durability over time. You would say a reliable software is not know for crashes and it works okay. I would translate it with ***Zuverlässigkeit***.

Statement: My answer is heavily opinion-based on a long-year experience in software business and engineering.

Answer (score 2):

In a situation where the exact meaning is relevant (as in a PRD) a definition is required. For everyday’s talk,

> I would translate it as *Zuverlässigkeit*, synonymously to *reliability*.

This seems to be the best fit. Instead, I would not translate the very narrow definition of

> - **reliability**: continuity of correct service;

as *Zuverlässigkeit*, because it only captures a small aspect of it. From the description, this should be *unterbrechungsfreier Betrieb*.